# Calculating python tree height for large data sets

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to get an efficient algorithm to calculate the height of a tree in Python for large datasets. The code I have works for small datasets, but takes a long time for really large ones (100,000 items) so I'm trying to figure out ways to optimize it but am getting stuck. Sorry if it seems like a really newbie question, I'm pretty new to Python.

The input is a list length and  a list of values, with each list item pointing to its parent, with list item -1 indicating the root of the tree. So with an input of:

5

4 -1 4 1 1

The answer would be 3 - the tree is: ({key:1, children: [{key: 3}, {key:4, children:[{key:0, {key:2}]}] }

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**25)  # new thread will get stack of such size


class TreeHeight:
    def read(self):
            self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
            self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

    def getChildren(self, node, nodes):
        parent = {'key': node, 'children': []}
        children = [i for i, x in enumerate(nodes) if x == parent['key']]
        for child in children:
            parent['children'].append(self.getChildren(child, nodes))
        return parent

    def compute_height(self, tree):
        if len(tree['children']) == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            max_values = []
            for child in tree['children']:
                max_values.append(self.compute_height(child))
            return 1 + max(max_values)


def main():
  tree = TreeHeight()
  tree.read()
  treeChild = tree.getChildren(-1, tree.parent)
  print(tree.compute_height(treeChild))

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: There is no question. If you are asking why it's slow. It's becasue you are doing several overkills, if your asking for an optimal version... well whole program would probably have to be redesigned. If you're new, good job! Though algorithmically bad, it's nice coding. You should go to the CodeReview SE. They love dissecting working programs.

Comment: Assuming most of the time is spent in the 'for' loops, substituting, map or a  list comprehension or a generator expression (depending on what you need) may be a good option.  Have a look here in the loop section https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips.  I have also found this article very helpful when trying to optimize in Python https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/.

Answer (score 1):

first, while python is really a great general purpose language, using raw python for large datasets is not very efficient. consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) or one of the many great [alternatives](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

second, if you're concerned with tree's height, and your tree is a write-once-read-always one. you could simply alter the code that reads the input to not only fill the tree but also measure the number of height.

this attitude makes sense when you don't expect you tree to change after been created

Answer (score 1):

Use DFS to avoid stack overflow in recursive calls. Use a marker to know the end of a level during the traversal.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def compute_height(root, tree):
   q = ListQueue()

   q.enqueue(root)
   q.enqueue('$')
   height = 1

    while not q.isEmpty():
        elem  = q.dequeue()

        if elem =='$' and not q.isEmpty():
            elem = q.dequeue()
            height+=1
            q.enqueue('$')
        for child in tree[elem]:
            q.enqueue(child)

    return height


tree = defaultdict(list)
parents = [4, -1, 4, 1, 1]

for node,parent in enumerate(parents):
    tree[parent].append(node)

root = tree.pop(-1)[0]

print(compute_height(root, tree))
```